# How to get stable WIFI connection between phone and router when thousands of irrelevant phones are around?

Tags: wifi

I want to use Android phones to check tickets at the gate of an event.
These phones are connected to a password protected router (WPA2) and a PC to validate.
That all works nicely in a test setting, but I'm worried it might collaps if there are many other competing phones around.

How can I get a stable WIFI connection between my phones and my router when thousands of irrelevant phones are around?

Do the other phones clogg the router with requests even when the router is password protected?

Shall I hide the SSID?

Answer (score 1):

If the WiFi network is password protected and you choose a unique SSID, I would not expect clients to try connecting.

Clients can tell from the beacon being broadcast by the AP, that this SSID is password protected, and that they don't recognize the SSID, so they don't have a password for it.

If you pick a generic name as your SSID, clients may mistake your AP for another AP which they do have a password for. In that case they will try to connect and fail. This will consume a bit of bandwidth on the wireless connection, and it will be a minor annoyance to both you and those clients. So make sure your SSID is unique and unlikely to have been used by someone else.

A hidden SSID does not sound like a good idea. If somebody else is going to bring up an AP in the neighborhood, they may look for beacons to know which frequencies are in use. If they cannot see your AP, they are more likely to start using the same frequency and cause problems for you.

If somebody is going to attempt a brute force attack on your password, there are ways to find even hidden SSIDs, as long as they are in use. So a hidden SSID is not the best way to keep them from trying. A better way to keep them from trying is to use the strongest encryption supported by your AP and phones.

Answer (score 0):

No device is going to try to connect to a password protected AP without explicit instruction from its user. When showing a list of available APs, the devices are only receiving, not transmitting. So I don't think this is something you need to worry about.